# Using .NET 7 ProblemDetails instead of Hellang

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to migrate from Hellang ProblemDetails to a native .NET 7 ProblemDetails. Can someone explain how to replace the Hellang.ProblemDetailsOptions.Map() method using a native ASP.NET Core components.

Now my code looks like:

```
      options.Map<ArgumentNullException>((ctx, ex) =>
      {
        var details = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails()
        {
          Title = "Null exception",
          Detail = ex.Message,
          Status = 409,
          Instance = ctx.Request.Path,
        };
        return details;
      });
```

In AspNetCore.Http.ProblemDetailsOptions we have only one method - CustomizeProblemDetails, and this method uses only ProblemDetailsContext, no Exceptions in any way.

Any suggestions on how this could be implemented?

Comment: If considering an alternative to throwing/intercepting exceptions in Hellang is an option, you could try DomainResult (https://github.com/AKlaus/DomainResult) that might be easier

Comment: @JoshNoe could you elaborate on your statement? I'm genuinely curious since I'm considering going that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try as below:

```
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails(x =>
{
    x.CustomizeProblemDetails = ctx =>
    {
        var exception = ctx.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>()?.Error;
        if(exception != null&&exception is FileNotFoundException)
        {
            .......
        }
        if(exception != null&& exception is ArgumentNullException)
        {
            ctx.ProblemDetails.Title = "Null exception";
            ctx.ProblemDetails.Detail = exception.Message;
            ctx.ProblemDetails.Status = 409;
          
        }
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseExceptionHandler();
```

I tried in a webapi project and Result:
[image]

Comment: IExceptionHandlerFeature always null in my case. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: make sure you've called  the middleware app.UseExceptionHandler();  before other middleware

Comment: I've called UseExceptionHandler() first, so it's most likely something else.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that could reproduce your issue? have you redirected to other location ? have you called other error handling middleware,I tried in a minial WebApi project and it worked well as I've shown